# How to force Asp.net 3.5 Menu Control to Rendered as UL List Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, xhtml, menu

As you all know Asp.net 3.5 and past generations Rendered as Table ( TR - TD ) form and this makes it heavy to load and blah blah blah.
Microsoft change the rendering methods of this control from table to UL LI in Asp.net 4.0

As I am using Asp.net 3.5 , Is there any solution to force this control rendered as a UL LI ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CSS friendly control adapters for ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/Menu.aspx) are doing precisely that. I've used them a couple of times and they always did the job.
They can be activated/deactivated for each control type. For the grid control for example they render the  tag, which as we all know is essential for easy styling.

Answer (score 13):

Simply Change Rendering Mode :)

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menu" 
                        RenderingMode="List" >
```

Comment: This makes big impact in menu layout! Work for .NET 4 and above